# Binary encapsulation in C++?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

1) What is binary encapsulation in c++, and does c++ support binary encapsulation?

I did some searching but all that I found was just encapsulation, which roughly is nothing but wrapping of data and methods in a class.

2) So what is the difference between encapsulation and binary encapsulation?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="binary+encapsulation" returns http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/569204-syntactic-encapsulation third from the top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quote from [this text](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0201634465/samplechapter/chap01.pdf) should clear things up:

> Whereas C++ does support syntactic encapsulation via its private and
>   protected keywords, the C++ draft standard has no notion of binary
>   encapsulation. This is because the compilation model of C++ requires
>   the client’s compiler to have access to all information regarding
>   object layout in order to instantiate an instance of a class or to
>   make nonvirtual method calls. This includes information about the size
>   and order of the object’s private and protected data members.

To clarify: Syntactic encapsulation is when you use the language syntax to encapsulate. In C++ this would be the private/protected keywords.

I found the text through [this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/569204-syntactic-encapsulation) which has a short explanation of the concept as well.

**Edit:**

As pointed out below there can exist binary encapsulation in C++. See [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) on Opaque pointers for more info.

Comment: @Keyser-----Its fine with answer because i am actually preparing for COM and not c++ for my exams, so i don't need much detailed explanation or programs in C++. I think you might find it funny that why i am studying COM ( since i heard people saying that its not used nowadays) but i can't do anything its in my University syllabus and i have to do it.

Comment: Then you might enjoy more of the text I quoted. It's entitled "COM as a better C++". Good luck with the exams!

Comment: Actually, binary encapsulation is possible in C++. If you look up the PIMPL idiom, you'll realize that you can abstract the exact state representation and hide it behind an opaque pointer, much like in C.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for pointing that out. The [wiki on opaque pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) was a good read. But, should this be considered a special case, or should one say that c++ **does** support binary encapsulation (in general)?

Comment: @Keyser: It's difficult to say. It can be done, but whether we consider that the language supports it or not is debatable. One could argue that the fact that it is possible (made so by allowing pointers to incomplete types) means it is supported while another could argue that since it requires hand written code it's not... it's always blurry what *supported* means.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are 2 types of Encapsulation
   Syntactical Encapsulation & Binary Encapsulation.
2. C ++ Doesn't support Binary Encapsulation.It only supports Syntactical Encapsulation.
3. Binary Encapsulation is supported by COM.
4. Best example of Binary Encapsulation is QueryInterface(void **) method of COM.
5. As this method takes one output parameter as void **.
   So it's double redirection as pointer is void **.
6. To get more details on this read Inside COM by Don Bix.